# Tracing Large Source Code

Tags: c, terminal, printf, trace, deduplication

I am trying to modify some open source code, but I having trouble approaching how to do so

The open source program that I am working with is called lessfs, and it has about four C files with up to 3000 lines of code. I am only concerned with one portion of the source code in order to modify.

Therefore, my question is, if I would like to add some print statements inside the code, how would I be able to see it?

Would I have to run the program or compile the program and run them individually? Or would it just be better to email the author and figure out a way to see certain items being printed while the program is running?

I have tried using GDB, but how do you do that when you are dealing with multiple large files?

I posted another form similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640838/gdb-lessfs-how-to-trace):

Thanks for your time in advance

Also, for more information about the source code that I am working with can be found here:

http://www.lessfs.com/wordpress/

Comment: What do you mean with "how would I be able to see it?"? Would printed information not always pop up on your console, as they usually do?

Comment: I would like to see specific attributes in the program being printed while it is running, so I added print statements, but nothing is being printed (that I added in the source code) when I run the program, do I have to compile that specific C file that I am working with individually? Or should I just contact the author on about how I might be able to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you add some print statement you have to compile the program again and then run it in order to see the printed text. I think this is obvious for a compiled languages.

Instead of print statements use GDB with breakpoints in order to inspect the values of the variables or the flow of the program.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that when I am running my own files, but how do I do that when this source code has a bunch of .h files and other C programs that are required for the program to run?

Comment: @humblebeast, Write a makefile or create a project in an IDE and add those files (the IDE will generate the makefile for you).

Comment: Ok, I will try the C version of Eclipse to run this program, try debugger to hopefully trace the methods and then eventually create a makefile; although, what does a makefile exactly help with?

Comment: An IDE will make the job but if you have enough time i recommend you to  study cmake http://www.cmake.org/.